# Can not deserialize value of type java.time.LocalDateTime from String

Tags: java, json, spring, date, spring-boot

I have following configuration:

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
//        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

and following dependencies:

```
ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    }
.... 
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket')
    compile("org.springframework:spring-messaging")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile group: 'net.jcip', name: 'jcip-annotations', version: '1.0'
    compile ("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

I added the following controller:

```
@PostMapping("/validation_test")
    public String testValidation(@Valid @RequestBody ClientInputMessage clientInputMessage, BindingResult result) {
        logger.info(Arrays.toString(result.getAllErrors().toArray()));
        return "main";
    }


public class ClientInputMessage {
    @NotEmpty
    private String num1;
    @NotEmpty
    private String num2;
    @Past
    private LocalDateTime date;
```

If I pass json like this:

```
{
      "num1":"324",
      "num2":123,
      "date":"2014-01-01"
    }
```

application prints following output:

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize value of type java.time.LocalDateTime from String "2014-01-01": Text '2014-01-01' could not be parsed at index 10
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1204f40f; line: 4, column: 8] (through reference chain: model.ClientInputMessage["date"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not deserialize value of type java.time.LocalDateTime from String "2014-01-01": Text '2014-01-01' could not be parsed at index 10
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1204f40f; line: 4, column: 8] (through reference chain: model.ClientInputMessage["date"])
```

Comment: Try "date":"2014-01-01T00:00:00". LocalDateTime in java does not accept "2014-01-01" as a valid date string.

Comment: @Jure Kolenko OOPS, it works

Comment: For a date-only value such as "2014-01-01", use `LocalDate` class rather than `LocalDateTime` class. Also, if your problem is solved then either you or Kolenko should post an Answer to be accepted to close this Question.

Comment: The oldfashioned `Date` class tended to be happy with just a date even though it really contained a point in time, that is, both date and time (save some time zone trouble). You may consider this a feature or a flaw. The new classes tend to force us to decide whether we want a date or a time or both. To me this is a step to the better.

Comment: @Ole V.V. date is not threadsafe

Comment: @Jure Kolenko, please add answer to accept

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Original answer:

LocalDateTime in java does not accept "2014-01-01" as a valid date string.

Some additional info:

If you don't actually care what type your date is (LocalDate, OffsetDate, ZonedDate, ...), you can make it a [TemporalAccessor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html), then use [DateTimeFormatter::parseBest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseBest-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery...-) to parse the date.

**P.S.**
string "2014-01-01T00:00:00" will be valid for LocalDateTime

Comment: FYI: The class docs for java.time advise generally to avoid using the more general interfaces such as `TemporalAccessor`. Such interfaces are intended for use only *within* the framework. To quote: *This interface is a framework-level interface that should not be widely used in application code. Instead, applications should create and pass around instances of concrete types…*

Answer (score 0):

You can simply tell the Deserializer that what comes should be a `LocalDate` even if you have a `LocalDateTime` in output, having care to have an alternative setter for your `LocalDate` *variant*.

Something as:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(as = LocalDate.class)
@Past
private LocalDateTime date;

public void setDate(LocalDateTime input) {
    date = input;
}

public void setDate(LocalDate input) {
    date = input.atStartOfDay();
}
```